# The difference between signed bytes and parity bytes

Tags: c++, byte

I'm reading some bytes out of a byte stream and they look like this:

```
OUTPUT:
48 -84 -79 -84 -73 -79 46 48 -84

SHOULD BE:
48  44  49  44  55  49 46 48  44
```

I'd like to turn these into ascii characters but those negitive symbols are confusing me.  This makes me think I don't understand signed bytes.  What on earth am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Post the code that reads them.

Comment: If possible, post us the code where you read the bytes.

Comment: I am paring down the code now.  It is kinda complicated, and I just grabbed the output from debug log.  sry, working on it...

Comment: What logic could transform `48` to `48` and in the same time `44` to `-84` ?

Comment: @ruslik:  `char transform_char(char c) { if (c == 48) { return 48; } else if (c == 44) { return -84; } throw char_not_44_or_48_exception(); }`, naturally.

Comment: @James, @Santa I see.. It's plain old 7-bit ASCII. The high bit have to be cleaned before output.

Comment: @Stephano are you analizing obfuscated scripts for IE?

Comment: @ruslik IE6 :) .  In all seriousness I'm reading from a serial port and outputting the signed byte in actionscript so it is a wee bit hard to show meaningful code here.

Comment: @Stephano you had to mention the magic word `serial` from the very begining.

Comment: For those wondering, when interpretated as 7-bits ASCII with parity, it reads: "0,1,71.0,"

Comment: Indeed.  Well done all around Sjoerd.

Comment: Why don't you post the *raw* input (unsigned bytes or bits) and *expected* output of said input?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like the highest bit is used as a **parity bit**, while your code assumes it is a **sign bit**.

- 48 = 011 0000  : 2 bits set -> add 0
  -> 0011 0000 = 48
- 44 = 010 1100  : 3 bits set -> add 1
  -> 1010 1100 = -84
- 49 = 011 0001  : 3 bits set -> add 1 -> 1011 0001 = -79
- and so on...

**Solution**: mask away the highest bit by using `(value & 0x7f)`.

Comment: Whoa.  You are correct sir.  The code is assuming it is a sign bit, but it is indeed a parity bit.  Well done indeed!  +1 and the win.

Answer (score 7):

For example:

```
 84 (dec): 0101 0100
-84 (dec): 1010 1100

 44 (dec): 0010 1100
```

The latter (`-84`) is two-complement of the former (`84`). With signed byte encoding, if the highest bit is set, then it represents a negative number.

Coincidentally, `44` (dec) is encoded like `-84` in signed byte except that its highest bit is clear.

Comment: +1 I think this clears it up for me nicely.  Sorry I can't show code easier, but I'll flush that one out myself.

Comment: +1 for setting me on the right track towards the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you are concerned with the 7-bit ASCII character set (all of US English is in there, for example). Since you are reading 8-bits at a time, the easiest thing to do would be to mask off the highest bit (which is the sign bit)

In C:

char letter= dataByte & 0x7F;

-84, with its top bit masked off, is 44.

Answer (score 2):

Read them as unsigned bytes.

Explaination: The first bit (highest) is taken as a +/- sign, not as a normal binary digit when you interpret it as a signed byte.

Comment: Not strictly correct. Values above (unsigned) 0x80 are indeed negative, but it is not a "sign bit" in twos-complement.

Comment: And it does not explain the relations between SHOULD BE and OUTPUT.

Comment: @theatrus: The more correct definition is that the most-significant bit has a decimal value of -128 instead of 128 in a signed 8-bit value. This has colloquially been referred to as the "sign bit" for decades. However, if you define "sign bit" to narrowly mean "a bit which indicates the sign", which is how it works in IEEE 754 floating point, for example, then two's complement does not have a "sign bit".  FWIW, invoking this definition of "sign bit" implies different representations for 0 and -0.

Answer (score 2):

It's a 8-bit signed integer. Like 32-bit integers, but with a smaller range.

Answer (score 2):

@Stephano Now we are getting somewhere :)

The most probably your UART is set to 7 data bits + 1 parity bit (high bit is parity), so that the number of set bits in the byte have to be even.

You can use it for error checking, and then reset it to obtain the real 7bit ASCII character.

Comment: +1 also correct.  Technically Sjoerd got in under the buzzer.  Well done though, cheers mate!

Comment: We were both on the right track. I didn't see your comments until after I had written my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What's a "byte"? In C++ language "byte" is synonymous with `char` type, which is simply an ordinary integer type that can be signed or unsigned. On your platform type `char` is probably signed (if `char` is what you are using), which is why you get signed values.

In other words, most likely you yourself used a signed type to read the values into, so expectedly you got signed results.

Of course, it is just a guess, since without seeing the code it is not possible to say what it is exactly you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your application is converting them to an int before writing them out. What's the code you're using to generate the output?

Answer (score 0):

When you read data from any source (a file, a network socket, etc.) it is only a stream of ones and zeroes. Usually they are delivered in groups of eight (i.e., as bytes) but it is entirely up to your code to decide how to interpret those bits.

Suppose a file contains this byte:

```
10101100
```

If you interpret it as a signed byte, this represents the value -84 in decimal.

If you interpret it as unsigned byte, then it represents the value 172 in decimal.

If your code is reading values into a variable of type `char`, then you would see -84, since `char` is signed by default. If you change the variable declaration to `unsigned char`, then you will see 172. The underlying bits are the same in either case, you're just telling the computer to interpret them differently.